# Now() function in Excel VBA macro stopped working

Tags: excel, vba, date, datetime, macros

I'm trying to set up a Warning in a prompt that I'm using in a VBA Command button in an Excel workbook.

It worked well two days ago, but it does not work at the present moment and I do not understand why. Here you have the code that was working before:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 
Dim wb As Workbook Dim FinalDate As Variant
Set wb = Application.Workbooks("Test")

FinalDate = InputBox("Introduce the final date for analysis in the
following format MM/DD/YYYY") 

'< Check that final date is in the correct format
        If IsDate(FinalDate) = False Then
            MsgBox ("The date you entered is NOT IN THE CORRECT FORMAT!!!")
            Exit Sub
        End If

'<Check that final date is NOT later than today
        If FinalDate > Now Then '< **This part is the one that used to work**
            MsgBox ("The date you entered is LATER THAN THE CURRENT DATE!!!")
            Exit Sub
        End If

            wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K2") = FinalDate
End Sub
```

This is the part that was working before, but stopped working yesterday:

```
If FinalDate > Now Then
    MsgBox ("The date you entered is LATER THAN THE CURRENT DATE!!!")
    Exit Sub
End If
```

At the present moment, every time I introduce any date into this prompt screen, no matter if it is later or earlier than the current date I get the Warning "The date you entered is LATER THAN THE CURRENT DATE!!!".

The only thing that has changed in the Excel Workbook is that there are several cells across the different spreadsheets that contain future dates from future appointments, but the function now() should check the system date, not the dates in the workbook, doesn't it?

Thank you very much,

Best Regards,

Yatrosin

Comment: You might want to reduce your example only to what is necessary to show what isn't working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are comparing a string entered by the user with a date returned by the now function.

This values are of two different types.

```
If FinalDate > Now Then
```

You should convert FinalDate to a Date with CDate()

```
if CDate(FinalDate) > Now Then
```

Comment: The only reason that `FinalDate > Now` would have occasionally worked is that is that it is performing a `String` comparison without the cast (`Now` is implicitly cast to `String`, not the other way around).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. I hadn't realize I was comparing a string to a date due to the fact that `IsDate ()` was not returning any errors.